# google chrome iframe body onLoad not working?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, onload

**EDIT: It does work (sorry).** Something in this script is causing it to stop in google chrome:

```
function checkLocation() {
  var loc = top.location.href;
  var suffix = "subpage.html";
  if (loc.indexOf(suffix, loc.length - suffix.length) !== -1) {
      top.location.href = "index.html";
  }
}
```

**Original post:**

I have IE 9, FF 3.6.3, Chrome (18.0.1025.151) and Safari 5.1.5 all installed.

This works in all of the browsers except google chrome.

I have a HTML layout which contains a named iframe. The iframe src changes to display the different pages. On one of the pages I have a script which is loaded onLoad in the body tag. This script doesn't load when the page is loaded in the iframe in google chrome only - it works fine in other browsers. Also, if I load the page directly into google chrome (not via an iframe) it works just fine.

How do I fix this?

Here is an example code:

```
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html> <head> <title> Example Page </title> </head>
       <body> <a href="subpage.html" target="targetFrame">View subpage</a><BR/>
              <iframe name="targetFrame"> </iframe>
       </body>
</html>

subpage.html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html> <head> <title> Subpage </title>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="subpage.js"> </script>
       </head>
       <body onLoad="initialise()"> Hello </body>
</html>

subpage.js
function initialise() {
    alert("Script loaded.");
}
```

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out its just a security exception

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame
with URL file:///C:/Users/.../website/index.html
from frame
with URL file:///C:/Users/.../website/subfolder/subpage.html.
Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

Once its online it should be fine.